# Calling a Rails method with : in front of the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I am working my way through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.  In **Listing 9.19**, he defines a private method called signed_in_user, but when he calls it at the top of the code he uses the following line:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

Why does he add a colon when he calls signed_in_user?

Answer (score 1):

`signed_in_user` isn't actually being called on that line. The method that's being invoked is `before_filter`, which is a Rails method. `:signed_in_user` is an argument to that method, and that's the kind of argument that method takes--a symbol that names a method to be invoked at runtime before the controller actions specified in the other argument (or all of the actions in this controller, by default).

Answer (score 0):

Because [Object.send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) take a symbol as the first parameter.

So if you want to use `Object.send` to invoke a method, a symbol is expected.